# What affected this steak?

Tags: steak

When my wife and I have steak one night, we usually make shaved steak sandwiches the following night.  We are sure to get enough steak for the first night so we can do this.

Last time I did this, the steak sandwiches came out tasting nasty.  There were some differences in my approach to cooking them.  I'm wondering if anyone can clearly see which one was the issue.

First, we used Sirloin Filet.  Not sure if this cut is too lean for good steak sandwiches.

Also, since we were not prepared to make the steak sandwiches on the following evening, I froze the steak for two days.  I then thawed for a day.  Quite a bit of blood had pooled in the container.

If I had to guess it was because of the freezing and thawing.  But I wasn't sure if the Sirloin Filet alone would have caused a noticeable difference.

Comment: What sort of 'nasty'? can you describe that?

Comment: Other than the usual delicious result; of or like a taste that no longer makes me want to eat it.  I can't characterize it other than saying it was not good.  We both ate half the sandwich and threw the rest out.

Comment: What cut do you normally use?

Comment: New York Strip.       .